# GetAsyncKeyState on windows 7 x64

Tags: c#, pinvoke, c#-2.0

I'm trying to use GetAsyncKeyState(i) on windows7 x64 with C# to get pressed keys. It works perfect on x86. Here are my codes:

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
public static extern int GetAsyncKeyState(long vKey);
[DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, ExactSpelling = true, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Winapi)]
public static extern short GetKeyState(int keyCode); 

        search = false;
        int key_my;
        for (i = 0; i < 255; i++)
        {
            key_my = GetAsyncKeyState(i); // this should return -3.... but it does 46...........
            if ( key_my == (System.Int16.MinValue + 1))
            { search = true; break; }
        }
        if ( search == true)
        {
           ...//using if to keys here.
        }
```

any IDEA?

Comment: That's a VB6 declaration.  Use pinvoke.net to find correct ones.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `GetAsyncKeyState` function should have a return type of `short` not `int` and it's parameter should be typed to `int` not `long`

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
public static extern short GetAsyncKeyState(int vKey);
```

Answer (score 0):

Though this question has already been answered correctly, I'd like to point out my experience using this answer and that putting it in one line does *not* work.

```
        if (GetAsyncKeyState(27) == (System.Int16.MinValue + 1))
```

does **NOT** work.

```
                int key_my = GetAsyncKeyState(27); 
                if (key_my == (System.Int16.MinValue + 1))
```

*does* work.

(I don't know why.)